# Как обрабатывать запросы, которые возвращают ссылки для переадресации с помощью org.springframework.http?

Tags: java

в общем делаю такой запрос к веб-сервису гугла(развернул скрипт)

```
final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(new Gson().toJson(['json':body,'name':name]));
ResponseEntity<String> resp = new RestTemplate().exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity,String.class)
```

но там переадресация, он возвращает в headers.Location ссылку, если делаю новый запрос, то ничего не выходит. на проекте есть только http библиотеки спринга и java